# Reference a newly opened Workbook to run code on it

Tags: excel, vba

I know I can open a workbook and have code run in the same workbook if the mapping to the file is pasted into the macro code.

I want to use an open dialogue box to select it.

This code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer, fd As Office.FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd

    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    .Title = "Please select the file."

    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xls?"

    If .Show = True Then
        fileName = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))
    End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks.Open (fileName)

For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
    total = Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
    Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
    after:=Workbooks("import-sheets.xlsm").Worksheets(total)
Next sheet

Workbooks(fileName).Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

allows me to select the file through an open dialogue box but then the workbook opens in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax looks wrong, but I'm surprised it's not generating an error message.  Try assigning the newly opened workbook to a variable and then reference it through that, like this for example:

```
Dim ImportBook as Workbook
Dim ExportBook as Workbook

Set ImportBook = Workbooks.Open (fileName)
Set ExportBook = Workbooks.Open ("import-sheets.xlsm")
```

However it looks like what you're doing is making a copy of the whole workbook and saving it to a new file, in which case there are probably better ways of doing that than one sheet at a time.

Would the [Workbook.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) method be more appropriate here?